# Inserting legends and co-ordinates in ndvi

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to know how to insert legends for the calculated ndvi in qgis. 
Also how to mark the co-ordinates in the ndvi calculated in qgis.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert legends by *right-clicking on your raster > Properties > Style* and set your **Render type** (e.g. Singleband pseudocolor and add vales, colors and labels):

[image: Raster properties]

Not sure how to mark or label coordinates, you can certainly hover over and identify coordinates and their associated values by using the **Value Tool** plugin (from *Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*):

[image: Value Tool]